# Adding framework in static library in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have added a third party framework in my static library in Xcode, later when i add this library to a project, i have to add this framework again. So is there any way exist by which i don't have to add that framework again in project.The reason for this i am developing an ad SDK, which uses a third party framework and i don't want to expose that framework to my publisher. Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Compile the 3rd-party lib and `ar -cvr` its object files along with the ones of your library.

Comment: (And yeah, google what `ar -cvr` does, I don't know how Xcode calls the archival process.)

Comment: Make sure you aren't opening your customer up to liability because you are using that third party framework.  That could be a pretty bad thing to do. It would be customary for them to know any third party content going into the app, as it can really be a legal problem for them.

Comment: @H2CO3 Thanks for your response. In 3rd party framework there is no lib file , only header files are present. Then what to do?

Comment: @russell Is it a C++ library? If it isn't, I doubt there be only header files. Are you sure?

Comment: @H2CO3 no it's objective c in header, but internally there may be other languages, there is only header file in framework which is provided for iOS integration . It's Speechkit framework from dragon mobile sdk for voice recognization.

Comment: @russell Then surely you do have a static library... `SpeechKit.a` or whatever...

Comment: @H2CO3 I double checked it, there is no .a file in their framework (i also checked their sample project). The framework looks like having same format as UIKit frameworks, which don't have .a file inside.

Comment: @russell well those are dynamically linked libraries of which the actual executable is moved to the dyld shared cache (as of iOS 3.1), so it's only an illusion they don't contain an actual .dylib. If a static library is build for iOS, there must be a .a file. Search for it using `find /path/to/SpeechKit.framework -name "*.a"`.

Comment: @H2CO3 I found a file named SpeechKit inside framework having 2.2 MB size. So i guess it's the complied file. But it doesn't any extension.   So is it the file i am looking for?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/31568/discussion-between-russell-and-h2co3)